# Catch all exception in C# winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, events, error-handling

in C# winform desktop application I'm trying to catch all exceptions possible to appear in the code, what I've tried:

```
  using System;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Controller
    {
        static class Program
        {
            [STAThread]
            static void Main()
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
                Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }

            static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message, "Unhandled Thread Exception");
            }

            static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show((e.ExceptionObject as Exception).Message, "Unhandled UI Exception");           
            }
        }
    }
```

I test it with attaching of "COM6" with form closing event without serial port in Device Manager, but I see only Visual Studio `An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code` report

How it is possible to collect errors data for winform application

Comment: As soon as an unhandled run-time error is encountered, execution stops. Unless you're reporting the error and letting it continue, you won't see any additional errors because the application has stopped running.

Answer (score 8):

That's actually not that hard to do.
I would advise to put any code for handling the exception into the mainform to keep the `program.cs` as clean as possible.

First in your `Program.cs` put this

```
static class Program
{
    public static Form MainForm = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

        MainForm = new Form1();
        Application.Run(MainForm);
    }

    static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Form1)MainForm).Application_ThreadException(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Then in your mainform put this

```
    public void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // All unhandled exceptions will end up here, so do what you need here

        // log the error
        // show the error
        // shut the application down if needed
        // ROLLBACK database changes 
        // and so on...
    }
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried this but same, I see only Visual Studio report with exception case like `An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code` with same serial port test and `MessageBox.Show` inside the `Application_ThreadException`, which I've added below `public Form1()` in `Form1.cs`

Comment: This will only catch unhandled execptions. It is possible that a library catches an exception and shows this info using a messagebox.show. In that case you will never catch it anymore because it was already catched elsewhere

Comment: Looked everywhere for a solution. This worked beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

You can use try-catch to catch the exceptions in all methods. Inside catch you can log the reason for the exception.

```
try
{
   // Your code that might throw an error
}
catch( Exception e )
{
   // What you want to do when the error is thrown
   Logger.WriteException(e);
}
```

I would prefer writing a static class 'Logger' and 'WriteException' method for logging the exceptions to a text file.

```
public static class Logger
{
    public static void WriteException(Exception exception)
    {
        string filePath = @"D:\Error.txt";

        using (StreamWriter logWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
        {
            logWriter.WriteLine("Message :" + exception.Message + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine + "StackTrace :" + exception.StackTrace +
               "" + Environment.NewLine + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            logWriter.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

There are several error logging methods available , you can use the suitable one for your application. You can use EventLog, Microsoft Logger etc.

Comment: Hello, yes this way I'm storing  data for each particular exception case, but I'm wondering, if it is possible to get single event with common report for any other possible cases, provided or not provided by  each individual exception condition already exist in separate  functions

Answer (score -1):

catch all the errors in one single point in your application is not a best practice. I suggest you to identify where your code may fails and use try/catch block to catch specific groups of errors instead. In this way you can control more better your application and you can identify more better the weaknesses of your code. For example:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {

    try{
      //Put here your code
    }
    catch{
    }
}
```

A generic "Exception" for sure can't help you or the user to identify a possible error in the application

Comment: Hello, yes  I use catching of exception for any possible case, but if it is available to  get common report for all cases, what exactly message content should be, how to handle this event